# How to test for correct behavior of onLoad/onAttach and onUnload/onDetach?

Tags: r, package, testthat

I have some functions defined in `.onLoad` which setup some global state and some functions in `.onUnload` which reset that state. Unfortunately, those don't seem to be cooperating with `devtools` functions, meaning I get weird warnings (in my case coming from the [websocket](https://github.com/rstudio/websocket) package) when I run `devtools::document()` or `devtools::test()`.

How can I best capture these in a test suite? Does it have to be external to `testthat`? I mean, I can think about saving a script in there to check manually, and potentially I could spawn another R process in a testthat test from that script. Has anyone got an example of this?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? Sometimes that increases other's willingness to help when they see some initiative. But, furthermore, I am trying the same with `.onAttach` and maybe we can benefit from seeing what we tried. I ended up putting all the logic into an extra function `ExecuteOnAttach`. Now I test `ExecuteOnAttach` and `.onAttach` does nothing but call `ExecuteOnAttach`.

Comment: Good question! Thanks for pointing out that I hadn't resolved this question, which I had completely forgotten about. I managed to resolve the problem, which was mostly related to regular bugs in my code. However, some of it had to do with me not understanding what code gets loaded when and how to properly collate the scripts so that it works right. I would I had made sure the code worked right before deciding the appropriate interface was having it available at package load.

Comment: I think I also was initially confused about what goes in `.onLoad`, `.onUnload`, `.onAttach`, and `.onUnattach`. Now my `zzz.R` file has very little code for each. I also did as you suggested of placing all my code in separate functions which could be tested. Of course, the websocket code wasn't really easy to test that way, unfortunately. Nevertheless, if you submitted that as an answer, I would accept it.